# removing multiple buttons with the same name

Tags: java, swing, button

Im adding buttons for a game but when removing the button in a loop it will only get rid of one button even though i added them in the same way

```
for(int i=0 - 1; i < 4 ; i++) {
    panelButtonsub.remove(buttonBlankItems);
    }
    panelButtonsub.setLayout (new GridLayout (intLayout,intLayout));
    revalidate();
    repaint();
```

Comment: Could you explain the code more? It is not clear what `buttonBlankItems` is.

Comment: you try to remove the same button multiple times

Comment: If you want help, you'll have to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `int i=0 - 1` -- Why?

Comment: Basically im creating a turn base game, so the item slot has 4 spaces and the code checks what item they are. The extra spaces are put in as "buttonBlankItems" using a loop, but the items are only displayed when the item tab is open, so i need help removing the blank items

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all the buttons in the panel you can use:

```
panel.removeAll();
```

If you want to remove the first 4 buttons in the panel you can use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4, i++)
    panel.remove(0);
```

If you are trying to remove a certain type of component from the panel then you need to start at the end to remove the components:

```
int components = panel.getComponentCount();

for (int i = components - 1; i >= 0; i --)
{
    Component c = panel.getComponent(i);

    if (c instance of BlankButton)
        panel.remove(i);
}
```

Where `BlankButton` is the component you created to represent the extra space by using `panel.add( new BlankButton(...) )`.

If you are trying to do something else then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @joshreilly, don't forget to "accept" the answer, by clicking the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

You must have distinct instances for each `buttonBlankItems` button. I guess that you are adding the same button 5 times and then you are trying to remove them.